# React.js setState does not re-render child component

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I am passing a list from the parent component's `state` to a child component's `<CheckboxList />` `props`. The list should then show in the child component. After fetching the list elements from the database I use `setState` to update the list but the child component is not re-rendered with the new list.

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {

    state = {
        users: [{ username: 'before' }]
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const result = [];
        db.collection("users").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
            querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
                let user = doc.data();
                result.push(user);
            });
        }).then(() => {
            this.setState({
                users: result
            })
        })
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <h1>List of users</h1>
                <CheckboxList list={this.state.users} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

The list shows `before` and it does not update with content from the database. I checked and the values are fetched from the database, they are just not passed to the `<CheckboxList />` after the `setState`. Can anybody help me?

Comment: How is `CheckboxList` implemented? It might be that it initializes state from the initial props, so that it doesn't change when `list` is updated.

Comment: Thanks Tholle, that was the problem. I was retrieving the `list` from the `CheckboxList`status and then using it through that. Now I have fixed. I am retrieving it in the `CheckboxList` 'render()`, storing it into a variable and then using from there it and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was retrieving the `list` from the `CheckboxList` status and then using it through that. Now I have fixed it. I am retrieving it in the `CheckboxList`  `render()`, storing it into a variable and then using it from there.